# Why does only of these xlwt functions work?

Tags: python, xlwt

I try to compare a matrix from matlab with one from Python in an Excel file. Therefor i try to use xlwt as shown in the code below.

The first part until wb.save('Z.xls') works, but the other one doesn't. Removing the first part doesnt help

```py
        wb= Workbook()
        ws=wb.add_sheet('P')
        for j in range (0,len(self.Z)):
            for k in range (0,len(self.Z)):
                ws.write(j,k,real(self.Z[j][k]))


        wb.save('Z.xls')

        wr= Workbook()
        ws=wr.add_sheet('S')
        for j in range (0,len(self.v)):
            for k in range (0,len(self.v)):

                ws.write(j,k,int(self.v[j][k]))


        wr.save('v.xls')
```

That's the error.

```
  File "M:\LambWaveModes_p\Aufruf.py", line 7, in <module>
    LWM([[3.5,1.5,0],[1.5,3.5,0],[0,0,1]])
  File "M:\LambWaveModes_p\LambWaveModes.py", line 49, in __init__
    LWM.calculate(self)
  File "M:\LambWaveModes_p\LambWaveModes.py", line 407, in calculate
    LWM.compwavenum(self)
  File "M:\LambWaveModes_p\LambWaveModes.py", line 484, in compwavenum
    ws.write(j,k,int(self.v[j][k]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What do I have to change?

I tried

```py
print(v[j][k])
```

right above ws.write and it printed v[0][0].

Comment: `ws.write(j,k,int(self.v[j][k]))` here you're taking elements from `self.v` but your `j` and `k` are in `range (0,int(len(self.Z)))`. perhaps you meant to use `len(self.v)`. oh and the `int` is not needed.

Comment: I tried that, but both have the same length so nothing changes, when i changed it. The int is nessesary, cause v contains complex numbers.

Comment: I meant the `int(len(...))`. the length of a sequence is already an integer.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I got rid of that

Comment: What are the dimensions of `self.v`?

Comment: 100*100. If i print v[j][k] it correctly shows v[0][0]. So the first two indices must be wrong in ws.write?

Comment: Two things you can try to troubleshoot: replace `ws.write(j,k,int(self.v[j][k]))` with either `ws.write(j,k,42)` or with `print(j,k,int(self.v[j][k]))`. If the first (with 42) fails then the problem's with `ws.write`. If the second fails (with print) then the problem's with `self.v[j][k]`

Comment: That last comment really helped me. I mixed up self.v and v and thats were the error came from. Thanks man

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!